# How do you express (Keys.Control | Keys.M) in F#?

Tags: f#, char, bit-manipulation

In C#, you can express characters for the `KeyPress` event in the form `Keys.Control | Keys.M`. In F#, `Keys.Control ||| Keys.M` doesn't work. What does?

**Edit**: Interesting indeed. Using `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control ||| System.Windows.Forms.Keys.M` as per Johannes Rössel's suggestion below in the F# interactive window works exactly as he shows. Writing it in a .fs file:

```
    form.KeyPress.Add (fun e ->
         if (e.KeyChar = (System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control ||| System.Windows.Forms.Keys.M)) then textbox.SelectAll() )
```

gives me the error `The type 'char' does not support any operators named '|||'`. So I probably misidentified the location of the problem. There is no typecasting from `Keys` to char.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is very vague.  Perhaps you could post a specific error instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+`:

```
Keys.Control + Keys.M
```

FWIW, `|||` works for me, though:

```
> System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control ||| System.Windows.Forms.Keys.M;;
val it : System.Windows.Forms.Keys = M, Control
```

Comment: You are right, I modified the question to show where I went wrong. What is the difference between `+` and `|||` in this case?

Comment: @Muhammad: `|||` is the bitwise or operator. `+` is addition.

Answer (score 4):

Just little addition to Johaness Rössel's answer, there is nicer (or 'more functional') way to do this using reactive programming.

```
form.KeyDown
    |> Event.filter (fun e -> e.KeyData = (Keys.Control + Keys.M))
    |> Event.map (fun _ -> textbox.SelectAll())
    |> ignore
```

Comment: I think you can use `Event.add` instead of `Event.map` and then drop the `|> ignore`.

Comment: @Matajon, thanks. I will be looking at FRP later. I was just translating a tool I already had from IronPython and I didn't have time to make it more functional.